# PODIO JSON Feed to C# Objects polymorphism

Tags: c#, .net, json, podio

I am writing a program to read a JSON string from Podio, and then convert the contents to c# objects.

But while reading the feed, I came across a strange format; At the same hierarchy-level of object, sometimes the value of the field [value] is a string but other times it is a complex object.

Example is below.

At some places it is like

```
"values":[
    {
        "value":"Bug on User Interface, Ajax sometimes does not load properly"
    }
],
"type":"text"
```

and then at the next item, at the same level in the hierarchy, it is like

```
"values":[
    {
        "value":{
            "perma_link":"https:\/\/ds-test.podio.com\/myworkspace\/files\/23529948",
            "mimetype":"image\/jpeg",
            "hosted_by":"podio",
            "name":"217820_274164679355286_689330144_n.jpg",
            "hosted_by_humanized_name":"Podio",
            "description":null,
            "thumbnail_link":"https:\/\/files.podio.com\/23529948",
            "link":"https:\/\/files.podio.com\/23529948",
            "file_id":23529948,
            "size":39698
        }
    }
],
"type":"image"
```

Note the value of "type": For the first instance it is "text" and then for the next it is "image". As they are on the same level of the hierarchy, I have no idea how to design the objects for them so that the `DataContractJsonSerializer.Read` method works smoothly.

Regards,

Comment: Is `"Bug on User Interface, Ajax sometimes does not load properly"` just an example you've entered to illustrate that it's a string instead of an object? And if so, can you update your question with a few examples of what's _actually_ returned?  Or is this string what is really returned?

Comment: There are many type returned. e.g image, description etc. so far description value of [value] field has to be string for type image value of [value] field has to be an object.

Comment: Hi Ali, I'd appreciate some feedback on my answer below - especially given it looks as though I was the only person to offer any suggestions, and I gave you quite a comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

Up front, I'm no JSON expert (I've dabbled), and while I'm a competent C#.net programmer, I've never worked with JSON from .NET.  I would've thought you'd have at least one good, definitive answer by now, but since you haven't had *any*, I'll offer my $0.02 worth, in case it's helpful to you.

This is a *valid* format, according to http://www.json.org. (I'm not sure if by saying it's a "strange format", you're saying that you think it's not valid, or just that you think it is unusual).

In both example cases you've described, there is a consistent pattern between them:

```
<string1> : <value1>,
<string2> : <value2>
```

where in all cases:

- `<string1> == "Values"`,
- `<string2> == "type"`,
- `<value1> ==  [ <object> ]` (ie `<value1>` is always an array containing a single `<object>`), and
- `<value2> == "a string describing the structure of the <object>"`

Also, `<object>` is either a string when `<value2> == "text"`, or it is a more complex object that contains 1 or more `<string> : <value>` pairs in a comma separated list when `<value2> != "text"`.

So, how to parse, assuming .Net can't handle this standard format out-of-the-box (I'm surprised it can't)...

- Build a class definition for each of *only the objects you are interested in*.  You should be able to glean the required structure from the JSON.
- Have you thought about running a string operation to "find/extract" the types you're interested in, and set up an explicit `DataContractJsonSerializer(Type)` for each of those types?
- Otherwise, more generally you should be able to treat everything within `<object>` when `<value2> != "text"`, as a `Dictionary<string,string>`, and then process this on a case-by-case basis as required, depending on your type specified at `<value2>` (or even transform these into your object "manually").

---

Further, I note that .NET 4.5 introduces this overload:

[DataContractJsonSerializer Constructor (Type, DataContractJsonSerializerSettings)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194418.aspx)

with settings such as:

- [DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat.aspx),
- [DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.DataContractSurrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.datacontractsurrogate.aspx).

And particularly interesting:

- [DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.KnownTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.knowntypes.aspx)

> ...a collection of types that may be present in the object graph serialized using this instance the DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.

These may be relevant, but I can't find any more information about any of these settings - perhaps something for you to experiment with.